# Take just numbers from array of objects without linq

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I need take just numbers from this array, how can i do that?

```
object[] midexArray = { "5", "0", 9, 3, 2, 1, "9", 6, 7, 9, 3, "7", "3" };
```

I need chose from this array just numbers and then sum them and return sum of numbers

Comment: You have asked a question with absolutely no detail, then explaining in peoples answers that you have restrictions. Please please pleas update the question with the appropriate information needed to answer this, with all the restrictions and what you expect to return

Comment: **need take just numbers from this array** meaning just remove them, which numbers do want to _take_? is there any pattern to it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use LINQ?

Comment: Because this task need do without linq

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like an effort to get others to do your homework without making an effort yourself.

Comment: Yeah i am with you here, this is extremely lazy and low quality. @Taifunov please read the help on asking a question

Comment: If it's a homework assignment or an interview question, that's fine, but this should probably be stated in the question, along with exactly what's allowed and what's not--e.g. "I can use for or while loops, but no extension methods". Also please show what your best attempt to solve the problem and tell us what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Firstly i tried to search it in web, but after 3 hours of searching i'm done, that's why i wrote it in this site i understand that you all just angry people, but if you don't want to  help, why you coming in topic and just wrote ? 
If you won't help just try find some topics, i know that now you all made many minuses but i'm ready for it ;)

Comment: Just so you know, no one here is actually angry with you. We're trying to help you construct a question that's more useful to the community and more likely to produce correct answers. If you can show some code you've written, and explain what went wrong, your question will be better received and some of the downvotes may even be reversed.

Comment: Ok, i will know this for the future

Comment: @Taifunov The goal of [SO] is to create a high-quality question/answer site: each question is expected to have some merit for other readers who encounter similar programming problems. From your comments, it has become apparent that you are looking for a solution that does more than is described in your question. I'd recommend using the answer you already have to continue to solve your problem. I didn't mean to come off as mean or angry, I just feel that you're doing yourself a bit of a disservice by asking someone else to do the full task for you. If you can't solve the rest of your task

Comment: feel free to post a new question with the code up to the point where you get stuck and we'll do our best to help. Note that questions here are always better received if you can show some attempt to solve the problem yourself, even if it's not complete or correct. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Jonh it's not task from my homework, i just find this example in internet and for me interesting how i can do that, but when i try i stucked, then i searched it's in web it was about 3 hours and then just i wrote it in this site, but you just think that you make hw for me, nope it's  not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this without Linq, you could loop through the items and check it is an Int.

```
var list = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in midexArray)
{
   if(item is int)
    list.Add((int)item);
}
```

**Update**

If your aim (as per comments) is to get the sum of numbers in the array, you could do the following.

```
var sum = 0;
foreach(var item in midexArray)
{
   if(item is int)
        sum+=(int)item;
}
```

Comment: Without list too, just from array

Comment: so you want to remove from the current array ? as in, you do not want to create a new array, but rather remove elemtns from exisitng ?

Comment: i need chose from this array just numbers and then sum them and return sum of numbers

Comment: @Taifunov That doesn't adequately explain the restrictions.

Comment: @Taifunov I have updated the answer to get the sum now. kindly check

Comment: Given an array of integers as strings and numbers, return the sum of the array values as if all were numbers.

Return your answer as a number.

Comment: @Taifunov that's a completely different question, and you should be doing _your own_ homework.

Comment: Thats exactly what you get if you run the last updated part. Variable sum would contain the sum of numbers. If you want it as a method, you can return sum

Comment: I believe your questions needs more clarity. The conditions doesn't seem to be told correctly. btw, the question doesnt quite say about linq